# How to fix a login issue on the new CiviCRM gitlab server?

Tags: gitlab

Here's the thing. I've had a user account at civicrm.org for years. Now that the old issues.civicrm.org is shutting down I wanted to check out the new gitlab server at https://lab.civicrm.org

That site tells me that I should login using my credentials from civicrm.org, only that doesn't work.

I'm keen to avoid creating a second user account on civicrm.org unless absolutely necessary as that will most likely just confuse things further. I'm assuming something is broken somewhere.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On https://chat.civicrm.org, mention this on the ~infrastructure channel and a Gitlab administrator will give a hand.

Comment: Thanks - i did scan through Mattermost, but couldn't spot a relevant channel. Must have missed that one.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but am a little confused by the answer. So I have to create a new account on a separate chat site in order to avoid having to create a new account on the new issue queue site?

Comment: @Demerit Accounts are typically approved within 24 hours regardless of whether you're on chat or not.  But you don't need to create a separate chat account - your civicrm.org login should work there immediately.

Comment: It didn't work though. It's an old account, which works on civicrm.org, but not the labs or chat.

Comment: @Demerit well THAT is something to bring up in ~infrastructure :)

Comment: I ended up creating a new mattersmost account and posted in infrastructure and they fixed it. See other answer here.

Answer (score 3):

If you can login to civicrm.org, but not lab.civicrm.org, please make sure that your username does not have a space (or other special characters) in it.

I think that Drupal lets you rename your account, but if you have any questions, you can ping @bgm in ~infrastructure.

https://lab.civicrm.org/infrastructure/ops/wikis/login-problems-with-gitlab